# Can you skip non utf-8 data in python csv?

Tags: python, csv, utf-8

I am dealing with a very large csv file in python where some lines are throwing an error "'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9b in position 7657: invalid start byte". Is there a way to skip lines that aren't utf-8 without going by hand and deleting or fixing data?

```
for filename in filenames:
f = open(filename, 'rt')
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
for row in reader:
    #process data for future use
```

I can't use the non-utf8 data because of later processes that require utf-8 use

Comment: Is your file encoded in UTF-8 and is broken? Or is it actually in some other encoding which you should simply handle correctly?

Comment: Or are you trying to print out the data to a non-UTF-8 terminal (like on Windows)?

Comment: You should show your code, you could possibly add a `try except` that just passes when this particular error is raised. But that would mean some data loss.

Comment: As you are speaking of UTF8, versions 2 and 3 of Python will behave differently. Do you want Python2 or Python3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a filter that reads a line as raw bytes, tries to convert it to unicode as UTF8 and then :

- if successful, passes it down to the csv reader
- if not, stores it for later analyzing

Assuming that you are using Python2, you could use something like :

```
class MyFilter:
    def __init__(self, instr, errstr):
        self.instr = instr
        self.errstr = errstr
    def __enter__(self):
        print("ENTERING filter")
        return self
    def __exit__(self, a, b, c):
        print("EXITING filter")
        self.instr.close()
        self.errstr.close()
        return False
    def __next__(self):
        line = next(self.instr)
        while True:
            try:
                t = line.decode('utf8')
                return line.strip()
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                self.errstr.write(line)
                line = next(self.instr)
        return line
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        return self.__next__()
```

You could then use it that way (assuming Python 2.7), getting all offending lines in err.txt :

```
with open('file.csv') as istream, open("err.txt", 'w') as err, MyFilter(istream, err) as fd:
    c = csv.reader(fd)
    for i in c:
        # do you stuff, eg: print i
```

If you use Python 3, you can use almost same filter class, simply replacing line `return line.strip()` with `return t.strip()`, in order to return a string and not bytes.

Usage is again almost the same :

```
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as istream, open("err.txt", 'wb') as err, MyFilter(istream, err) as fd:
    c = csv.reader(fd)
    for i in c:
        # do you stuff, eg: print (i)
```

Per your comment, you want to also filter lines containing null characters. This only needs a slight change in filter, the `while` block becoming (Python 3 version) :

```
    while True:
        if b'\x00' not in line:
            try:
                t = line.decode('utf8')
                return t.strip()
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                pass
        self.errstr.write(line)
        line = next(self.instr)
```

Comment: @NimishTodi : if you use only Python 3, you can remove last method `def next(self): return self.__next__()` which only exists for Python 2 compatibility.

Comment: This pretty much fixes it... Thanks! Would you happen to know how to configure the filter to also address the error "line contains null bytes"? I'm not quite sure how to trigger an error in the __next__ method for that case

Comment: @NimishTodi : Once the filter is set up, it is easy to adapt it. See my edit.

Comment: Are you assuming that just becaues utf-8 codec can decode it, that it is utf-8 encoded?    Is that a fair assumption?

Comment: @GreenAsJade I have already found a case where a large utf8 encoded CSV file was *wrongly* edited with a Latin1 editor. Instead of browsing file *by hand*, I used that kind of filter. For french language in Latin1, the risk that a correct sequence of accented characters are wrongly recognized as an utf8 one is almost null.

Comment: Good to know - this area is one of black magic, and easy to get wrong by sampling a few cases!